# PHP mails always ends up in the spam folder

Tags: php, email

i have an issue here, my mails sent from my PHP script never gets delivered to my inbox, but spam instead. Any help on how to get it to the inbox. Thank y'all
Here is my code sample

```
public function sendMail($name,$email,$message)
{
    $this->validateInput($name,"Empty Name","Invalid Name");
    $this->validateEmail($email,"Empty Email","Invalid Email");
    $this->validateLargeData($message,"Invalid Message","Empty Message","Message Too Short");
    if (empty($this->errors))
    {
        $fromName = $name;
        $fromEmail = $email;
        $from   = "From: $fromName <$fromEmail>\r\n";
        $reply = "Reply-To: $fromEmail\r\n";    
        $mime = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $content = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers = $from.$reply.$mime.$content;
        if (mail("support@findit.com.ng","Contact",$message,$headers))
        {
            echo "<div class='success1'>Thank you $name, we will get back you immediately.</div>";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div class=''>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

**edit**
Pls here is the header information i am using

```
$fromName = $name;
$fromEmail = $email;
$from   = "From: $fromName <$fromEmail>\r\n";
$reply = "Reply-To: $fromEmail\r\n";    
$mime = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$content = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$mailer = "X-Mailer: PHP's mail() Function";
$headers = $from.$reply.$mime.$content.$mailer;
```

@cyberomin

Comment: @Pekka, done so in the past. Any help concerning the question?

Comment: @Cyberomin what do you mean by in the past? I don't understand

Comment: What Pekka is trying to say is: To raise the chance people will help you, it's advised to accept some answers of your previous questions first.

Comment: i do also always, just watch this space, will do so when i get the right answer.

Comment: @Cyberomin: You're supposed to click the V-shaped checkmark next to the best answer of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your headers are complete:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$headers .= "From: aaa.bbb <aaa@bbb.ccc>\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP's mail() Function\n";
mail("xxx@yyy.zzz", "subject","message",$headers);
```

And if you are on shared hosting, it might be that there's a blacklisted spammer on your ip.

The best suggestion I can probably make is to try a different way of sending your emails. For example [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Comment: @Cyberonmin: You also might wanna have a lookt at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250234/sending-mail-with-php-escaping-hotmails-junk-folder

Answer (score 0):

We can only give you an exact answer if you give us the headers of the mail in your spam folder, but I think that it's because you are sending from a computer that has an IP in an IP range that contains consumer internet connections. Email from consumer computers usually is spam.

Comment: @Cyberomin thejh means the headers that are included in the email your receive. There is a whole host of information sent in an email header, some of which you cannot edit. If you can update your question with that information, it will help people to give a fuller answer.