# How to send email in Hotmail's INBOX instead of JUNK using PHP?

Tags: php, email, sendmail

As my question says, is there any possible way to send an email from your script into the inbox than junk ?
I used mail() and very variations with headers, then a lot of tests with PHPMailer , set SMTP etc but nothing. All of the emails are sent into the Junk folder.

I am curious on how I get so many newsletters or simple emails from blogs into my inbox and I can not send properly an email notification about a purchase that a user made.

I am using shared hosting on bluehost.

Please share me your thoughts or code (if there is any).

Comment: The question you need to be asking is why does the email client consider what you are sending to be junk.

Comment: another anonymous downvoter is hiding behind the screen. Do not afraid, I do not bite.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why are all mails sent via php's mail() go to spam box but not mails sent directly from the domain's account?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032286/why-are-all-mails-sent-via-phps-mail-go-to-spam-box-but-not-mails-sent-directl)

Comment: @Nikolai the question is fine but it isn't without precedence here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting mail past the big mail provider's spam filters reliably requires more work and access than any single developer has.

You can start with things you can control, like RDNS records for your IP, SPF records for the mail server, setting up DomainKeys, etc. That'll help.

But you'll never negotiate the whitelist access legitimate e-mail companies have to get their mail to these clients and the daily work they do to stay on those whitelists and remove their IPs from blacklists.

The short answer: If you want programmatically sent mail to reach inboxes reliably, then use the services of someone in that business.

http://www.sendgrid.com

http://www.postmarkapp.com

http://aws.amazon.com/ses

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I was looking for such services. I have mailchimp also in my mind.

Comment: MailChimp is built around double opt-in mailing lists, not transactional mails like purchase receipts. That's what these companies specialize in.

Answer (score 2):

Generally this has everything to do with the mail server and protocol you are using...

Mail sent through php using sendmail does not have to be verified and can be sent anonymously... this is *probably* a reason why your email's are ending up caught in spam folders...

I recommend using an authenticated smtp server there verifies the sender's identity (that also needs to match the `from` header), you will have a much better chance getting to the inbox.

Also, realize that if this is unsolicited email, nothing can help you and you will (if not now, eventually) be black listed for spamming, and at that point no one can help you, **or want to...**

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If you are sending what an email client considers to be "junk", it will end up in the junk folder. Solution: improve the quality of what you are sending.

This is a good reference: [sending mail with php & escaping hotmails junk folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250234/sending-mail-with-php-escaping-hotmails-junk-folder)

Answer (score 1):

This totally depends on the `mail client`, not the `mail` function.  I know outlook does some checking on the header fields present in the message to help determine if a mail message is junk or not, for instance MX/A Record Lookups.  Other clients may as well.  Also, if your message contains 'junk content' (such as the words c1alis or z@nex), mail clients may probably tag your message as junk as well.

If you are sending your e-mail from a non-existent e-mail address, try sending it from one that does exist and see if it is not tagged as junk.

Answer (score 0):

I had some success with [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/). Try to send mails through an SMTP server from the same domain as the `from` header.