# PHP mail() and hotmail

Tags: php, email

I'm launching a product today and COMPLETELY OUT OF NOWHERE hotmail accounts can't receive email from my php mail() script.

I've searched around and found others with similar problems but haven't found a true solution

```
$Email = "my@email.com";
$Name = "My name";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ". $Name . " <" . $Email . ">\r\n";
$body = "bleh";

mail($recipient, "My email", $body, $headers);
```

It sends fine to GMail etc just not hotmail.

Anyone conquered a similar problem? It doesn't go into SPAM either

Comment: Did you check the spam folders? I'm not saying that your mail is spam... but sometimes the email providers can be overzealous with the spam detection.

Comment: It's probably blocked by the spam filters. Getting past those it's not easy, but see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7101416/1027148 for a few tips.

Comment: You can avoid these problems if you use PHPMailer or SwiftMailer.

Comment: It's not going to spam/junk

Comment: Well, sometimes the “big” email service providers don’t even bother to put emails into the spam folder, but delete/reject them straight away if _they_ think they are spam or malicious. As @AmalMurali said, try using PHPMailer or SwiftMailer – those are better at adding additional headers and the overall conformity to RFCs relevant to sending emails, than the simple emails you’re sending out via PHP’s `mail`. If that doesn’t help, then consider implementing SPF correctly.

Comment: @JamalLanten I see no other mention of `$recipient` in `mail($recipient, "My email", $body, $headers);` and is not assigned. Plus if anything, it should be `mail($recipient, $Email, $body, $headers);` - is this the actual code that you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SMTP instead. Mails from mail() often go to spam folder, because servers can't verify source of message.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the exact code you're using?

A long shot, but could there be a conflict in your e-mail validation (if there is one)? A while ago I had an issue where regex wasn't catching hotmail accounts, took me so long to figure it out.

Else, I agree with other responders that some mail services simply delete what they think is spam, I think there's a "spam level" thing where you set how aggressive the spambot is.

Hope this helps.