# Codeigniter Mail function sends mail to spam folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am using codeigniter mail function. Its sends mail perfectly. But all the time mail going to the spam folder. How can I overcome this.

**Function**

```
function msg_now(){
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->load->library('parser');

        $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $email_id='test@test.com';
        $name=$this->'test';
        $this->email->from('test@gmail.com');
        $this->email->to($email_id);

        $this->email->subject('Test subject');

        $this->email->message("<p>Lorem ipsum dummy content</p>");
        $this->email->send();
}
```

Comment: Try to avoid subject name with `test` try with other subject name.

Comment: There are lots of reasons an email service will throw emails from a random server into the spam folder (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250234/sending-mail-with-php-escaping-hotmails-junk-folder)

Comment: `test@gmail.com` is this real gmail id? if not try to replace with some real registered gmail id and check

Comment: am using a valid email address for sending mail, this is my sample email id.

Answer (score 2):

```
    $this->load->library('parser');

    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'google email id',
        'smtp_pass' => 'password',
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('google email id','Title'); // change it to yours
    $this->email->to(your send email id);// change it to yours
    $this->email->subject('you subject');
    $this->email->message('your message');
    if($this->email->send())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
```

Comment: $this->load->library('parser'); is the key to avoid spam. Please note it...

Comment: how will the issue be resolved by just loading a library?

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for mail to go in spam, but easy solution for it is to set the headers of the mail before sending and giving it priority.

Here's how to do that in CodeIgniter. The function is `set_header()`:

```
$this->email->set_header($header, $value);
```

also check [this link](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html) for reference.

It has always worked for me.

Comment: Codeigniter doc's now located here. http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Comment: thanks, actually I was using previous version docs