# Codeigniter send email is goes into spam box using amazon ec2

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-ec2, spam, email-spam

This is my code:

```
 $config = array(
       'protocol'  =>  'smtps',
       'smtp_host' =>  'ssl://smtps.googlemail.com',
       'smtp_user' =>  'donotreply@eezybee.com',
       'smtp_pass' =>  '******',
       'smtp_port' =>  '465',
       'mailtype'  =>  'html',
       'smtp_timeout' => '4',
       'newline'   => "\r\n"
      );
    $this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->to('donotreply@eezybee.com');
$this->email->cc();//$this->input->post('cctxt')
$this->email->from('donotreply@eezybee.com');
$this->email->subject('Test subject');
$this->email->message('Test message');
$this->email->send();
echo  $this->email->print_debugger();
```

This email is going into spam box.

Comment: Error shows failed to authenticate password. Make sure you are using correct login credentials

Comment: which hosting you're used....cpanel or windows

Comment: login credentials are correct. @BSB

Comment: Server is amzon @Mahesh

Comment: have you tried with tls and port 587..?

Comment: yes i tired 25, 465 and 587

Comment: The problem is solved. In protocal instead of smtp used smtps. But message goes in spam folder not in inbox

Comment: open the spam message and give not a spam option...next time it will come to inbox

Comment: That's not the solution. I cant tell my users to do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter Mail function sends mail to spam folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424899/codeigniter-mail-function-sends-mail-to-spam-folder)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Give proper subject of mail so it will not go to span. '$this->email->subject('Test subject');' change subject here

Comment: It jsut for you guys real subject will be the page name like Contact us page, Help center page

Answer (score 0):

First, you have an error in the google's SMTP SERVER, it must look like

```
$config = array(
   'protocol'  =>  'smtp',
   'smtp_host' =>  'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
   'smtp_user' =>  'donotreply@eezybee.com',
   'smtp_pass' =>  '******',
   'smtp_port' =>  '465',
   'mailtype'  =>  'html',
   'smtp_timeout' => '4',
   'newline'   => "\r\n"
  );
$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->to('donotreply@eezybee.com');
$this->email->cc();//$this->input->post('cctxt')
$this->email->from('donotreply@eezybee.com');
$this->email->subject('Test subject');
$this->email->message('Test message');
$this->email->send();
echo  $this->email->print_debugger();
```

Then, for this to work you must enable access for less secure apps in your google account, since you are not using OAUTH.

[Enable access For less Secure Apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)

Good Luck!

Comment: No when i am using this config aaray. Mail sending stop. My server is https so I need to use smtps. Now my issue is why it goes in spam